# problems with using wordnet in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordnet

i've been tryin to use wordnet to generate the synonyms of a word. i've found that to used wordnet function i have to

1. Download the WordNet prolog database , gunzip, untar etc.
2. Invoke Syn2Index as appropriate to build a synonym index. It'll take 2 arguments, the path to wn_s.pl from that WordNet downlaod, and the index name.
3. Update your UI so that as appropriate you call SynExpand.expand(...) to expand user queries with synonyms.

i have downloaded WordNetProlog database. i dnt understand the second and third point here...
can anyone help...
thank u in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try analyzing the Framenet which is an implementation for wordnet, as in the links in  [this page](http://ptl.sys.virginia.edu/ptl/members/matthew-gerber/software#WordNet_API) .

May be you can get an idea. I suppose that the process you referred to in step2 refers to a  source code which is in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to download a standalone program that queries the local database, e.g. I use [cygwin wn](http://cygwin.com/packages/WordNet/WordNet-3.0-2). Then you can use it as follows:

```
$ wn wordnet -over

Overview of noun wordnet

The noun wordnet has 2 senses (no senses from tagged texts)

1. wordnet -- (any of the machine-readable lexical databases modeled after the Princeton WordNet)
2. WordNet, Princeton WordNet -- (a machine-readable lexical database organized by meanings; developed at Princeton University)
```